# Date listing at postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
and date(p.date_of_sale) <= current_date
```

I try this code and I got an answer like that.

[image].

But an error is shown like that.

[image].

Please watch 2 screenshots because I am not fluent in English and I don't know how to explain with text. That's why I add 2 screenshots.

Comment: hello @Newbie, welcome to StackOverflow. Please replace the pictures by plain text in your question and explain us what is your expected result and why yourquery result is wrong.

Comment: @Edouard my expected result is now we have 2023 week 1 right, but the result is also including 2023 week 52. I don't want to include this 2023 week 52 because that's not reach. Thank you bro.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from `to_char(p.date_of_sale, 'yyyy "-week" iw')` where

`iw` = week number of ISO 8601 week-numbering year (01–53; the first Thursday of the year is in week 1)

whereas `yyyy` = the year on 4 digits (not the ISO8601 year)

These two parameters are sometimes not consistent for instance for 2023 January the 1st :

```
SELECT to_char('20230101' :: date, 'yyyy') => 2023
SELECT to_char('20230101' :: date, 'iw') => 52
```

If you want to be consistent, you can either :

```
select to_char('20230101' :: date, 'YYYY"-week" w') => 2023-week 1
```

or

```
select to_char('20230101' :: date, 'IYYY"-week" iw') => 2022-week 52 (ISO8601 year and week)
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y6MlAoBy)